# How can I pass a Regular Expression through a function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to validate some fields passing a different pattern to a validation function.

```
send.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  let pattern = /^[A-Za-zÁ-Úá-ú\s]{3,15}$/;
  let nameIsVal = regexValidator(pattern);

  if (nameIsVal) {
    return true;
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});

function regexValidator(pattern) {
  if (!pattern.test(this.value)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: In `regexValidator`, `this.value` is `undefined`. The context of the click handler is not preserved when calling another function. You should just pass `this.value` as a parameter of regexValidator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are in a class. Make sure that the `this` keyword points to the correct instance in your event handler, either with the `.bind()` keyword or with an arrow function.

I would register the handler like this:

```
send.addEventListener('click', (event) => this.checkRegex(event));
```

Or if your environment doesn't support arrow functions, this should work as well:

```
send.addEventListener('click', this.checkRegex.bind(this, event));
```

Then I would add the methods to the class like this:

```
checkRegex(event) {
    let pattern = /^[A-Za-zÁ-Úá-ú\s]{3,15}$/;
    let nameIsVal = this.regexValidator(pattern);

    if (nameIsVal) {
        return true;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}

regexValidator(pattern) {
    if (!pattern.test(this.value)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```